# Importing SAS Enterprise library into SAS University

Tags: sas

I am trying to open an library which i am using in SAS Enterprise at course on my SAS University version at home.
I was told by my tutor to use this kind of code to import library.

```
proc cimport;

run;

filename x1 "/folders/myfolders/x1";
proc cport lib=mylib file= x1;
run;
```

but when i try to do this i get this type of error

```
 ERROR: Invalid file, /folders/myfolders/x1.
```

When i add this library in the way suggested [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWBOEy9wSjo) :

```
libname mylib "/folders/myfolders/x1";
```

i do not get the invaild file error but due to same encoding issue beetwen verison i cannot properly use this lib.

What is the proper way to import this library?

Comment: A library is a reference to a location or file. Do you have a location with some files you're trying to reference or a specific file? What is the extension of the file you're trying to access? SAS UE questions are better posted to communities.sas.com because most are already answered on there for a new user.

Comment: Location with some files. The extension is sas7bdat.

Comment: If the extension is sas7bdat, you would move the files to your myfolders and should see them in the library with a libname statement. Are you not seeing them in the library or what issue are you encountering. Make sure to undo everything and clean up the files first, you may have accidentally damaged them.

Comment: I am seeing them in the library but i cannot access some of them and when i use the library i get the :NOTE: The PD2.ORDERFACT.DATA data file is in a different operating system format or its encoding does not correspond to the session encoding.  Cross Environment Data Access will be used, which may require additional processor resources and slow down the work.

Comment: That is not an error, it's a Note that tells you it may take additional resources and you can still use the file. You can convert it if you want, just write it back out. `data pd2.orderfact; set pd2.orderfact; run;` Make sure your code is 100% correct otherwise you may destroy the file. If you have a backup give this a try.

Comment: There's a full section in the documentation if you feel like looking into it some more: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=movefile&docsetTarget=p0mvwvg25ceml5n1c2digfpk6vkh.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en